# Ugly shadows around applications

Tags: unity, compiz, windows, effects, compositing

When I updated to 11.10, I thought that any problems would be solved and all graphical glitches would be better. After upgrading, my whole system got borked, and everything looked ugly. I ended up fixing most everything, but for one thing.

The shadows for any application is ugly. It is hard to describe, so I hope the picture helps.

Notice the odd shadows. [image: The shadows are all wierd]

They also are common after closing a window or moving it to a different workspace

I know this is a small problem, but it still bugs me. Any fix for it?

Comment: It looks like those shadows are transparent through to your desktop. Nifty! Have you been messing around with Emerald or Compiz in 11.04 before upgrading?

Comment: Yes I did, but nothing with shadows

Comment: I'd like to add that this issue seems to be related to transparent backgrounds (like in gnome-terminal) being vertically-mirrored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thik it's the ***'Blur'*** effect in **CompizConfig Settings Manager**. A few days ago I tried to add blur to my transparent Menus and ended up in having this nice shadows (that reflect your Desktop but mirrored vertically). Try disabling the *'Blur'* effect and see if the shadows disappear.

Comment: Which blur? motion blur or blur windows?

Comment: I played around with blur for windows got that effect and by turning the window blur effect off I got rid of it. But now I'm unable to reproduce it...damn. I think at the moment Compiz has a lot of strange effects.

Answer (score -2):

Oh boy. I'm sure there's a way to disable shadows somewhere, if I find out how I'll let you know. For a temporary fix, when you are logging in, click the cog icon next to your name and select Ubuntu 2D.